# Filter array for latest by distinct name (javascript)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to get the latest result for each distinct name, in javascript.

Similar to this post, which was sql: [Get Latest Rates For Each Distinct Rate Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700619/get-latest-rates-for-each-distinct-rate-name)

What is the simplest way to do this in javascript?

The best I could think of so far is to create an array of unique names, then filter result for each name, sort those results in descending order by date, then push the first one into a new array.  Seems like a lot though.

Below is an example array:

```
[{"name": "John", "points": "400", "date": "2011-01-05"}
{"name": "John", "points": "410", "date": "2011-06-31"}
{"name": "Jane", points": "147", "date": "2011-09-21"}
{"name": "Jack", "points": "68", "date": "2011-07-14"}
{"name": "Jack", "points": "100", "date": "2011-10-30"}]
```

Results should look like:

```
[{"name": "John", "points": "410", "date": "2011-06-31"}
{"name": "Jane", points": "147", "date": "2011-09-21"}
{"name": "Jack", "points": "100", "date": "2011-10-30"}]
```

Comment: Just iterate over the list and track the latest result for each name in a map. If the next value is later, then replace it. Boom - O(n)

Comment: Thanks Danny.  What would that look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort first by dates descending, then reduce to unique:

```
var data = [{
        "name": "John",
        "points": "400",
        "date": "2011-01-05"
    }, {
        "name": "John",
        "points": "410",
        "date": "2011-06-31"
    }, {
        "name": "Jane",
        "points": "147",
        "date": "2011-09-21"
    }, {
        "name": "Jack",
        "points": "68",
        "date": "2011-07-14"
    }, {
        "name": "Jack",
        "points": "100",
        "date": "2011-10-30"
    }
];

data = data.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date));

var result = data.reduce((accum, record) => {
    if(!accum.find(entry => entry.name === record.name)){
        accum.push(record);
    }
    return accum;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Push or replace the objects in a new array, if either of the two conditions match:

1. If item does not exists in new array  (Push)
2. If item exists and
   existing item's date is older (Replace)

```js
const data = [
  { name: "John", points: "400", date: "2011-01-05" },
  { name: "John", points: "410", date: "2011-06-31" },
  { name: "Jane", points: "147", date: "2011-09-21" },
  { name: "Jack", points: "68", date: "2011-07-14" },
  { name: "Jack", points: "100", date: "2011-10-30" }
];

const latest = [];
for (let item of data) {
  const found = latest.findIndex(l => l.name === item.name)
  if (found !== -1) {
     if(item.date > data[found].date) {
         latest[found] = item; // replace
     }
     continue;
  }
  latest.push(item); // add new
}

console.log(latest);
```